# Integral Inequality for Functions in C1

Tags: integration, derivatives, inequality

From a longer proof, I am trying to prove the following auxiliary statement:

Let $f$ be a function in $C^1([0,1])$. Then it holds: $\vert f(0) \vert \leq \int_{0}^1 \vert f^\prime(x) \vert + \vert f(x) \vert dx$.

Can someone help me? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Of course, I added my attempt to this post.

Comment: Okay, thanks guys. I got the proof and will answer my question soon here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for the case that anyone has a simliar question, here is a proof:

By the fundamental theorem of calculus, we obtain $f(0) = - \int_0^x f^\prime(t) dt + f(x)$ for any $x \in [0,1]$. Consequently, using the triangle inequality and the properties of the integral, $\vert f(0) \vert \leq \int_0^1 \vert f^\prime (t) \vert dt + \vert f(x) \vert$. Now, integrate w.r.t. $x$ and this yields the claim: $\vert f(0) \vert = \int_0^1 \vert f(0) \vert dx \leq \int_0^1 \int_0^1 \vert f^\prime (t) \vert dt + \vert f(x) \vert dx = \int_0^1 \vert f^\prime (x) \vert + \vert f(x) \vert dx$.